# Toolbar возвращает null

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, null

Всем доброго времени суток! Есть фрагмент, в котором реализуется `Toolbar`. В нем есть метод:

**MainFragment.java**

```
public Toolbar getToolbar() {
    return mToolbar;
}
```

Когда я использую этот метод в главной `Activity` (к которой присоединен фрагмент), то он возвращает null:

**MainActivity.java**

```
MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
Toolbar toolbar = mainFragment.getToolbar(); //Toolbar всегда равен null
```

Вопрос: как получить Toolbar?

Comment: Судя по приведенному коду `MainFragment.java` у вас `mToolbar` и не инициализирован. Вот он и `null`.

Comment: @Plem Логично. Однако я его инициализировал в onCreateView. `mToolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);`

Comment: @AlphaWinner, однако метод `onCreateView()` не был у вас вызван, т.к. его вызывает система после добавления фрагмента в активити, чего у вас не происходит. Вам надо сначала добавить фрагмент в активити (что обычным способом совершается асинхронно) и только после этого тулбар будет инициализирован и доступен. Лучше всего это сделать вызвав метод активити из фрагмента после того, как он присоединится к активити.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, действительно, fragment transaction вызывался после метода `getToolbar()`. Но это, к сожалению, проблемы не решило. ­`Toolbar` все равно равен `null`.

Comment: Расставьте брейкпоинты и проверьте что за чем вызывается и почему не находится. И вызывается ли вообще.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja уже делал это, не знаю в чем была причина. Решил не тратить время, а привязал Toolbar к MainActivity, а после этого в MainFragment вызвал `Toolbar toolbar = ((MainActivity)getActivity).getToolbar`. Это сработало.